# Javascript cross-platform native mobile app with background geolocation

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, background, geolocation

I have been trying to write a cross platform app that will run on at least android and ios, but I need it to be able to get the latitude and longitude of the device while in the background (device in sleep mode or app out of focus).

I've tried cordova (as well as phonegap and ionic) and looked at nativescript but none of them seem to be able to do this.

I know that there is a plugin available that makes it possible for free but this only works on ios and I don't want to spend 350$ buying the version for android.

I have also bought appcelerator titanium and if it is possible using that I can do that too.

In summary, does anyone know of a cross-platform, javascript native mobile app framework that can access geolocation while in the background?

Comment: This plugin works very well: https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation

Comment: I tried that plugin in cordova but when trying to build I got build failed which stopped when I removed the plugin

Comment: I use this plugins: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode to run in background, and https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation to get coordinates. They works very well!

Comment: I have tried this but the geolocation coordinates didn't update in the background using that plugin